# How can we configure "Pods with limited network activity" and save money in billing?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I am receiving a suggestion like below:

***Pods that have not received meaningful traffic (less than 500b/s) over the last 7 days are suggested to be reviewed as potentially abandoned workloads. Remedies could be scaling down replicas, deleting, resizing, or notifying their owner.***

Can you suggest what config should I do?

Comment: why don't you go for serverless paradigm

Comment: @TusharMahajan there are multiple microservices and each service has a common network file system (NFS) and all services communicate via cloud pubsub. so because of requirement of NFS we can not move to serverless.

Comment: The pods in question have a minimum of replicas defined? If that is the case you could reduce this number.

Comment: yes It is already defined as 1 only @RubenM

Comment: There is also this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/understanding-autoscaler-decisions)  that could help you understand this behavior. Could you have a look into it and let us know if you notice any incongruence with your setup and the behavior described in the documentation.